# Force iframe to scroll

Tags: html, iframe, scroll, scrollbar

I have an absolutely horrible webform that renders into the following:

body -> form -> table -> thousands of divs -> iframe -> body -> thousands of divs -> iframe -> body -> table

Eventually I find the table that contains the actual data, the user makes his view smaller and the data cannot be seen, so there needs to be a scrollbar. I have been applying overflow:auto, width:100%, height:100% on many elements but never seen the right scrollbar to appear. Initially, the page renders with a few of the parent elements having overflow:hidden, however after changing them as I was inspecting the page nothing happened. Is there any way to force the scrollbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
<iframe src="p" width="300" height="500" scrolling="yes">
</iframe>
```

OR

Put your iframe inside a fixed height div and put css property as scroll-y:auto.

```
<div class="iframe_container">
<iframe></iframe>
</div>

div.iframe_container{height:500px;scroll-y:auto}
```

Comment: Satya you mean overflow-y:auto? never heard this scroll-y property

Comment: Please check this link:      http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_overflow-y&preval=auto

Answer (score 0):

try use alternate scroller https://jamesflorentino.github.io/nanoScrollerJS/

or make it with css reset http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

or universal reset, in start of your css style:

```
* {
  vertical-align: baseline;
  font-weight: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-style: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
  border: 0 none;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  }
```

then see what tag makes horrible

or just use **firebug** and on the fly find and fix awfl content/tag.